# time Range picker to select time range, with hours mins and seconds android

Tags: android, android-timepicker

time  Range picker to select time range, with hours mins and seconds android

Is there any library which supports seconds also

the only one i found was

https://github.com/tittojose/TimeRangePicker

but it does not support seconds

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
   int time=(picker.getCurrentMinute() * 60 + picker.getCurrentHour() * 
   60 * 60) * 1000;
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
   String formatted = format.format(time);
```

Comment: i need a timerangepicker not timepciker, i posted a wrong question please check the edit